# Frame rate function for browsers

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

Here is a frame-rate counter I wrote. Is the use of `requestAnimationFrame` redundant, or important?

Re-writing this function to not use `requestAnimationFrame` results in similar output.

```
const now = performance.now.bind(performance);
const raf = window.requestAnimationFrame;
const log = console.log.bind(console);
const ONE_SECOND = 1000;
let count = 0;
let start = now();

const go = 
    raf.bind(window, ()=> {
        if (now() - start >= ONE_SECOND) {
            log('FPS: ' + count);
            count = 0;
            start = now();
            return setTimeout(go, 0);
        }

        count++;
        setTimeout(go, 0);
    });

go(); // 61, 60, 59, 60, 59...
```

**Edit:**

In light of the comments, this is an amended implementation:

```
const raf = window.requestAnimationFrame;
const log = console.log.bind(console);
const ONE_SECOND = 1000;
let count = 0;
let start = performance.now();

const go = 
    raf.bind(window, (now)=> {
        if (now - start >= ONE_SECOND) {
            log('FPS: ' + count);
            count = 0;
            start = now;
            return go();
        }

        count++;
        go();
    });

go();
```

Comment: Well you should be using requestAnimationFrame *or* setTimeout, not both. Which one you want depends on what you're trying to do, of course.

Comment: Why that `setTimeout(go, 0);` instead of just `go()`?

Comment: Also, it's worth knowing that native functions (e.g. now, requestAnimationFrame, console.log) aren't required by the standard to behave like normal functions. For example, binding them like you're doing may not work in all browsers.

Comment: @Bergi because I don't want to blow the stack. I am probably wrong in my assumption however... Based on your question, I presume the use of raf avoids building up the stack by itself.

Comment: @BenAston Bergi is correct - requestAnimationFrame will work in a similar way to setTimeout, triggering on the start of the next animation frame. In fact it's the entire point of the function!

Comment: Notice that you don't need to use `performance.now`, the `raf` callback does already get a high-resolution timestamp as its argument. And it seems that you're not counting continous frames per second, but rather log "frames in the last second" in more-than-one second intervals.

Comment: So `requestAnimationFrame` will stick something onto the heap and register it in a browser-internal location for later invocation thereby avoiding building up the call-stack?

Comment: @Dave: In fact, [there is a standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#ecmascript-binding) that requires them to behave like normal functions. Of course, you will find old browsers that pre-date that standard and have "creative" bindings

Comment: @BenAston: Yes, requestAnimationFrame is guaranteed to be asynchronous.

Comment: @Bergi I have updated the function in light of your comments. But your comment describing the logic of the function implied that the output would not be meaningfully correspondent to the frame rate of the browser. Is that so? Furthermore, my question still stands, does the use of `requestAnimationFrame` rather than `setTimeout` alter the correctness of the frame rate count? I am trying to get a reading of the framerate as best I can.

Comment: Well, you basically have `Math.floor(FPS)` - if frames take longer than one second, your constantly at `0` for example. `console.log((count + 1) * ONE_SECOND / (now - start))` might be more appropriate.

Comment: "*does the use of requestAnimationFrame rather than setTimeout alter the correctness of the frame rate count?*" - yes of course, if you'd only use `setTimeout` it has nothing to do with frames any more.

Comment: @Ben Aston The short answer is that requestAnimationFrame was invented to solve the shortcomings of setTimeout(0) when used for frame-based operations (i.e. animations). setTimeout(0) will often behave in a frame-like way, but browsers have different timer resolutions, among other complications. Also requestAnimationFrame may slow down if your page is in the background, etc.

Comment: @Bergi (r.e. the standard): Good to know. Clearly I'm behind the times.

Comment: @Bergi Your comment to the question - if you make that the answer I will accept. Although you must concede that it has *something* (albeit rather tenuously) to with frames because the cb supplied to a `setTimeout` can only be executed if a job on the queue completed, likewise painting. Thanks a lot for the improved count calculation. PS: have you considered this before or did you just come up with that calculation on the spot?

Comment: @BenAston: Pretty much on the spot. I'll see how I can squash my comments into an answer.